# Improve performance of a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to improve the performance of the view `All_Risks`, can anyone help me to do this?

The select statement that builds the view is as follows

```
SELECT     
   dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.RiskID, dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.HRASnapshotId, 
   dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.RiskDate, dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.RiskTypeDescription, 
   dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.AgillicUserId, dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.SequenceNo, 
   dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.RiskValue, dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.RiskLevelDescription, 
   dbo.BE_RISKTYPE.RiskName, dbo.BE_RISKTYPE.RiskTypeCatagory, 
   dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.OrganisationID
FROM         
   dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.BE_RISKTYPE ON dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.RiskTypeDescription = dbo.BE_RISKTYPE.RiskTypeDescription AND EXISTS
                          (SELECT 1 AS Expr1
                           FROM dbo.BE_CompanyInfo
                           WHERE (dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew.OrganisationID = OrganisationID))
```

It has been suggested I bring the code from the view it references `Risk_RiskDataNew` into the view `All_Risks`

This is the select statement from the view `dbo.Risks_RiskDataNew`

```
SELECT     
   BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskID, BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.HRASnapshotId, 
   BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskDate, BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskTypeDescription, 
   BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.AgillicUserId, BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.SequenceNo, 
   BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskValue, BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskLevelDescription, 
   BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.OrganisationID
FROM         
   dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced AS BE_Risks_Sequenced_1 ON dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.RiskTypeDescription = BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskTypeDescription 
                                                  AND dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.AgillicUserId = BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.AgillicUserId 
                                                  AND dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.SequenceNo = BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.SequenceNo + 1
WHERE     
   (dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.RiskValue = 1) 
   AND (dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.RiskLevelDescription NOT LIKE BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskLevelDescription)

UNION ALL

SELECT     
    RiskID, HRASnapshotId, RiskDate, RiskTypeDescription, AgillicUserId, 
    SequenceNo, RiskValue, RiskLevelDescription, OrganisationID
FROM
    dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced
WHERE     
    (SequenceNo = 1) AND (RiskValue > 1)
```

Comment: Can you add the actual execution plan for All_Risks?

Comment: `VIEWS` are actually nothing more than just queries, if you talk about performance in `SQL`, `TABLE CREATION CODE` and `INDEX DEFINITION`s are a need to know to build efficient queries (or views for that matter ;)) So if you don't include more details into your question this is just pretty much guessing.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.RiskLevelDescription NOT LIKE BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskLevelDescription`? Unless `BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskLevelDescription` contains '%' built-in, you might get better performance with `dbo.BE_Risks_Sequenced.RiskLevelDescription <> BE_Risks_Sequenced_1.RiskLevelDescription`.

Comment: Dave Gugg, how do i attached the execution plan, i dont seem to have the attach button ?

Comment: Dave Gugg i have queried the view but it times out after 40mins! is there any suggestions without the use of execution plan, firstly because of amount of time to run query and secondly i dont think i have permissions to attach files on the laptop i am using!

Comment: Do you views selecting from other views? This is highly likely to generate suboptimal execution plans.

Comment: To view an execution plan in `SQL Server Management Server` right click in the area where your query is and select `Include Actual Execution Plan` and run the query. Make a screen shot from that plan and upload it to somewhere (imgur for example) and link it in your post.